# Install Sonerezh as a subdomain in Nginx

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

when installing Sonerezh it indicates to me that it does not find install. I put the configuration code of the subdomain musica:

```
server {
            ## Escucha en el puerto 80 (HTTP)
            listen 80;

            server_name musica.dominio.com;

            location / {
                    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
            }
}

server {
    ## Escucha en el puerto 443 (HTTPS)
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name musica.dominio.com;

    ## Certificados
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/musica.dominio.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/musica.dominio.com/privkey.pem;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/musica_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/musica_error.log;

    root /srv/www/musica;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }


    location / {
        alias /srv/www/musica/app/webroot/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ //musica/index.php?$args;

        location ~* /([^/]+_[0-9]+x[0-9]+(@[0-9]+x)?\.[a-z]+)$ {
            try_files /img/resized/$1 /index.php?$args;
            add_header Cache-Control 'public';
            expires 14d;
            access_log off;
        }


        location ~ /(.+\.php)$ {
            alias /srv/www/musica/app/webroot/$1;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/musica.sock;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DH$
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
```

}

[Sonerezh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq9Sr.png)

Log of Sonerezh:

```
2017/05/18 08:31:31 [error] 1579#1579: *1502 open() "/srv/www/musica/install" failed (2: No such file or directory),
```

---

I have modified the configuration file and it gave me the 403 Forbidden error

```
server {
    ## Escucha en el puerto 80 (HTTP)
            listen 80;

            server_name musica.dominio.com;
            root /srv/www/musica/public_html/app/webroot;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/musica_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/musica_error.log;

    index index.php;

        location ~ /.well-known {
               allow all;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                expires 14d;
                add_header Cache-Control 'public';
        }

       location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/musica.sock;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        }
```

}

Comment: The error message says there's no files in the directory "/srv/www/musica/install". That seems like a pretty good clue. Check for files and check permissions of those files, relative to the user Nginx is running as. Nginx usually runs the daemon as root, but runs the workers as another user - check nginx.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end changing the name of the folder:

sonerezh ----- >> musica

And restarting the server started working